# How to carry href link information forward from page 1 to page 2's PHP form?

Tags: php, html

I have a number of different pages that I want to all lead to the same form page, but carry information about what page a user clicked on to get to the form page once the form has been filled out.

Specifically, I just want the property name to be carried forward and emailed along with all the other form information.

How do I get the information contained in the search bar `?property=68yorkville` to show up in the email thats sent via the PHP form to my inbox?

**EDIT:**

I realized it would be better if I just share my code directly to make things easier:

Page 1: http://agentboris.com/listings/test-listing-page.php

Page 2 (with form): http://agentboris.com/listings/test-form.php?property=68yorkville701

Separate PHP File Form Code:

```
    <?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Please use the form.
    echo "Error, please return to last page.";
}
$property = $_GET['property'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$spambot = $_POST['spambot'];

if ($spambot != 'Yes') {
    $spambot = 'No';
}

//Validate first
if($spambot == 'No')
{
    echo "Please go back and check the 'I'm not a Spambot' box.";
    exit;
}

if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)||empty($tel)) 
{
    echo "Name, email and phone number are mandatory.";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}




$email_from = "alex@agentboris.com";
$email_subject = "Real Estate";
$email_body =

"PROPERTY: $property. \n \n".

"NAME: $name.\n \n".

"MESSAGE:\n 
$message. \n \n ". 

"PHONE NUMBER: $tel.\n \n".

"EMAIL: $visitor_email.\n \n".

$to = "alex@agentboris.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: ../contact/thankyou.php');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend to use GET with form data just for protecting the data so I would use the server session to store all the form data.

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['user_email'] = 'example@mail.com';
```

Then, in the next page, you can read it as a simple variable. (You need to start the session previously).

You have more (and better) examples here: http://php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: hm, this is inetresting, it might work. i tried starting a session on the first page then calling it with the $_SESSION['property'] function but it didn't work. could adblock be a problem?

Comment: No. Adblock not works on the server side. Do you have enabled the session in your php.ini file? And also, are you sure you started the session with session_start()?

Comment: i did start the session with session_start()? php in the first page, and i set the variables needed. they didn't carry through to the email message though. im also not using a php.ini file, i have a seperate php file with the form code.

Comment: @AlexBanman You need to start the session everytime you access to the $_SESSION var. So, in 'form 2' you need to start it to.

Comment: this worked, thank you. i think it would also be interesting to collect the address of each property if they browse multiple properties, do you think thats possible? not necessary now, but it might be useful later.

Comment: @AlexBanman I think I'm not understanding you. Do you refer to something like the method array_key_map? http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php

Comment: possibly, i mean like this: lets say i visit 3 different property pages and i want all their names to show up in the $_SESSION['property'] field. is that possible? im new to php so i dont know much about arrays.

Comment: Why dont you save an array inside a $_SESSION property? Example: $_SESSION['names'] = array('John Doe', 'John Doe 2');

Comment: That looks like it might work, how do I implement it? Do I just add "= array" after "$_SESSION['property']"?

Comment: Yes, then you can access to the stored data with a foreach or just writing the property like this: $_SESSION['property'][0].

Answer (score 0):

```
$email_message = "";

foreach ($_GET as $k=>$v) {
   $email_message .= $k . "=" . $v . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you can just pull property with a `$_GET` like this:

```
$property = $_GET['property'];
```

and then just include `$property` as a field in your email message.  This should include whatever variable was in the URL.

**Edit:**

I see your problem. Your variable is not passing correctly from agentboris.com/listings/test-listing-page.php. It is coming through as agentboris.com/listings/68yorkville701-contact.php. You have constructed your contact link incorrectly, so there is nothing to grab with your get variable.  This URL:

```
http://agentboris.com/listings/68yorkville701-contact.php
```

Should be changed to

http://agentboris.com/listings/test-form.php?property=68yorkville701

then on this test-form.php?property=68yorkville701

call the variable `$property= $_GET['property'];`

It should work.

Comment: Thats what i thought too, but for some reason its not working. I've edited my question with more information if that helps.

Comment: hold on, I think I can help

Comment: thanks. i actually, i made it a hidden field on the form so it wouldn't show up for users, but does that mean the information wont get transferred?

Comment: that's not the issue.  You need to include it in the message variable

Comment: oh wait you already did that;  I removed my edit.   I'm not sure why it's not coming through;  can you echo out the variable before you send it to make sure it is populated?  Also is everything else coming through?

Comment: still not working, i tried echoing the $property value but it just carries me through to the Thank You page. i can echo a regular word, but when i use the $property value it doesn't work. everything else is coming through.

Comment: could adblock be a problem?

Comment: no it wouldn't be adblock.  remove the header redirect to test it.

Comment: when you say nothing, do you mean it was not echoing out the GET variable on the page? If it doesn't show on the page, that will tell us that  the problem is with the way it is being pulled.

Comment: sorry, thats right, it didn't show anything, just a blank page.

Comment: To be clear, comment out the header redirect, then right after `$property = $_GET['property'];`  add an `echo $property;`  If that works, please confirm that all of the other fields are being sent through in your email, particularly those fields in `$email_body`.

Comment: I see your problem.  Your variable is not passing correctly from http://agentboris.com/listings/test-listing-page.php.   It is coming through as http://agentboris.com/listings/68yorkville701-contact.php.   You have constructed your contact link incorrectly, so there is nothing to grab with your get variable.  I'll edit this

Comment: see edit again.  I tried this from the contact link in the middle of the page;  it brought the wrong url.

Comment: i just tried that again, i had tried it before that way as well, it hasn't worked so far. thanks for your help though

Comment: oh, i see what was going on here. thank you for the heads up on this, i need to update those links. the links i was referring before to were on the side of the page, the boxes with "Book a Showing" and "Contact". i forgot there were links in the text.

Comment: ok that's good.   Of course you can use sessions as suggested by another answer;  I just was explaining how GET works